# Error while Saving document library as a list template

Tags: powershell, list-view, list-template

I have a document library with item count above 6510 which exceed the list threshold. I have the doc lib to be saved a list template, WITHOUT content included. i tried it from library settings but it kept on loading and didnt execute.

Than i tried a powershell script and even it kept on executing, when i checked the server resource , powershell wasnt taking any resoruce. Is there any best way to execute it or my script needs to be fine tuned?

```
 $site = get-spweb("mysiteurl") 
$list = $site.Lists["List_Name"] 
$list.SaveAsTemplate(“Incidents Forms Template”,”Inc Template”,”Template for arched data”,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too faced the same problem, List template was not being saved then I realized that default maximum size for document in document library is 50MB by default (as List Template Gallery is document library). So I updated maximum document size from Central Admin - Manager Web Application - General Setting.

after that list template saving worked successfully.

Comment: But i am just trying to save the template without the content, does it still needs to take the max size of library?

Comment: Yes you need to increase the max size.

Comment: I changed the max size to 1000MB, yet the script continues to execute for more than an hour but didnt complete. Processor utilization for the Powershell window is '0' , is this the general behavior or execution?

Comment: It took a bit of time, but completed the execution. Thank you